# How to show image name n edit view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My issue is when I create a TextBox, it shows an image name but on type file it does not show its name and no file is chosen in it.

I want to show image name instead of "No file chosen".

```
public ActionResult userprofile(int? id)
{
    var user = db.Personaltables.Find(id);
    return View(user);              
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult userprofile(Personaltable u, HttpPostedFileBase file, HttpPostedFileBase file1)
{
    db.Entry(u).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

    if (file != null)
    {
        PersonaltableEntities db = new PersonaltableEntities();
        string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + ImageName);

        // save image in folder
        file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        u.AttachPicture = ImageName;
    }

    using (PersonaltableEntities entity = new PersonaltableEntities())
    {
        var t = new Personaltable()   // make variable of table 
                    {      
                        AttachPicture = u.AttachPicture,
                    };
          
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

In Razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("userprofile", "personal", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label other">
            Attach Picture
        </label>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AttachPicture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" data-val="true" data-val-required="File is required" /> <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AttachPicture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[Image name is stored in database and show in text box but in file type is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V44Uo.png)

[No file is chosen - why it is not stored in it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3d5.png)

Comment: Have you click the "Choose File" ?

Comment: That is not possible. You need to show it in another control like Label or anything. The control only showing filename when you choose to upload.

Comment: Just to understand your question I would like to ask: what exactly did you mean by saying replace the “No file chosen” with image name? Do you mean changing the model error message and set it to incorrect uploaded image name? Like : ModelState.AddModelError("", “the new error”);